# jQuery: finding ancestors siblings with matching content / tree walking

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
     <td class="TargetRow">Not this one</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody> ... </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
     <td class="TargetRow">This one</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody> ... </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="ContextRow"> ... </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Given the above HTML I'm trying to find a way of getting the contents of the preceding **tr** of class **TargetRow**.  I.e. for the first preceding tbody that contains a **td.TargetRow** return the **td.TargetRow**

I'm using jQuery, at present I can get hold of the *tbody* containing the ContextRow using:

```
 jQuery(contextRow).parents("tbody").first()
```

How can I now find the previous sibling of that *tbody* that contains *tr.ContextRow*?

If there was just a way for me to say from **contextRow** walk up the DOM tree until you find an element matching **"td.TargetRow"** then that would be ideal.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your description, but when you say *"find the previous sibling of that tbody that contains tr.ContextRow"* it sounds like you want to find the previous `<tbody>` that contains an element with the class `.contextRow` and get its `.targetRow`.

If that's what you want, try this.

```
jQuery(contextRow).parents("tbody:first")
                  .prevAll('tbody:has(tr.ContextRow):first td.TargetRow');
```

If you meant to say `td.TargetRow` then do `'tbody:has(td.TargetRow):first td.TargetRow'`.

Comment: $(contextRow).parents("tbody:first").prevAll("tbody:contains(.TargetRow):first") -- was what I was after, thanks very much

Comment: @chillitom - You're welcome, but be aware that `:contains()` matches the given text, while `:has()` matches the given selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('.ContextRow').closest("tbody").siblings('tbody td.TargetRow:last');
```

EDIT: last not first

see it work: http://jsfiddle.net/wU6h9/

Answer (score 0):

`$(".ContextRow").closest("tbody").prevAll().find(".TargetRow").eq(0).css({color: "red"});`

This returns the single closest previous `.TargetRow`

http://jsfiddle.net/LfWg3/3/

Answer (score -2):

[Closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) - `.closest()` does exactly what you need.

Gets the first ancestor element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

Your query would be,

```
$('.ContextRow').closest('tbody').siblings('tbody td.TargetRow').last();
```

It will return one object( unlike parents, which returns multiple element until top), or zero if id didn't find one.